# Unexpected EOF while Lens up is starting the Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes (RKE) test environment that I'm working on ,and up until last week my Lens app worked fine.

My lab is running on Ubuntu 20.04.
3 nodes.
1 NFS server which is also my Ansilbe server.
All these is running on Vmware workstation.

## Today when i open the Lens, i see this error:

when i connect to my Cluster, after a couple of seconds, i see the error:

E0322 08:42:41.679547 5801 proxy_server.go:147] Error while proxying request: unexpected EOF

E0322 08:42:41.701049 5801 proxy_server.go:147] Error while proxying request: unexpected EOF

E0322 08:42:42.200974 5801 proxy_server.go:147] Error while proxying request: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\xfa\x00\x06\x00\x10\x01@\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00\x00"

malformed HTTP response

**And this is my Kubeconfig file:

=========================**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:

- cluster:
  api-version: v1
  certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUM0VENDQWNtZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFTTVJBd0RnWURWUVFERXdkcmRXSmwKTFdOaE1CNFhEVEl5TURFeU1ERXlNREV5TVZvWERUTXlNRE>
  server: "https://192.168.245.182:6443"
  name: "test-cluster"
  contexts:
- context:
  cluster: "test-cluster"
  user: "kube-admin-test-cluster"
  name: "test-cluster"
  current-context: "test-cluster"
  users:
- name: "kube-admin-test-cluster"
  user:
  client-certificate-data:
  client-key-data:**

Even when i want to configure a new Cluster in Lens, and upload the configuration file, after a few seconds, i get the error i pasted above.

I'll appreciate your help on this.
(already opened a new bug in github for lens App).

I also attached a screenshot from the Lens logs while it's trying to load the cluster.[image]

Best regards,
Nahum.

When i want to configure a new Cluster in Lens, and upload the configuration file, after a few seconds, i get the error i pasted above.

Hopefully, the screenshots I've added will help.

This is The error i get from Lens.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXjj9.png)

This is the Proxy Address in my cluster environment, as you can see, i have resolving to the PROXY.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQI4I.png)